# plink is closing after scriopt is executed in windows .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using .bat file to connect remote server to run an application, below is the .bat file

"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" -i "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\private.ppk" user_Name@20.223.45.63 "/path/Scripts/GetFolderList.sh /path/to/dir";

this is working fine, I mean this connecting to remote location but I am not getting output because of in windows task manager I can see the plink.exe and psftp.exe is not auto closing when close manually I get output.

I am not understand where is the mistake.

please help me out.

Thanks
Akshay Chakre

Comment: I'm not sure that's a batch file issue. Does it work fine if you run the same command from a command prompt? Is it executing the correct command from inside the batch script, i.e. are the quotes etc. correct? I don't understand about the auto-closing thing sorry (and I think you've run a few sentences together) - can you explain that more?

Comment: OK, but that doesn't help me understand what's going wrong on the Windows server. One idea to try would be remove the trailing semi-colon because I don't think that's necessary but I don't think it would break things either.

Comment: see my app is deployed on windows server and this works on unix server so when I run this app on windows its goes to connect unix via windows .bat file that I post above. when I run app the .bat file is runs and I get to connect unix but I am not getting script output that used in script, but same time I open the task manager on windows server and close plink.exe and psftp.exe I get script output  in app. here is the problem is both plink.exe and psftp.exe have to close automatically.

Comment: Have you read the plink help - http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-options - in particular you could try using `-batch`.

Comment: Vicky@ Link is good that you gave me. but my case is different because My all setup was working fine before today with same .bat file I do not know why its not working today.